# How to delete record in activejdbc with no primary key?

Tags: activejdbc

My table does not have a primary key. So when I try to delete a record

```
Table t = Table.findFirst("col = ?", var);
t.delete();
```

I get below exception. Any directions?

`org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ... "ID": invalid identifier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveJDBC does require an PK to operate. In case like yours, you need to override the `delete()` method, form a query that identifies your record, and call Base.exec() or DB.exec() methods internally. For clues on implementing, see the original [Model#delete()](https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/main/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/Model.java#L257) method. Do the same, but only generate a different query.